# Read email and phone number from Facebook Profile

Tags: iphone

I try to read email address, phone number from Facebook profile details to my iPhone Application. But, from my Facebook profile, I got name details, location details like that. But I can't get email and phone numbers.

In my program, first I get authentication using Oauth. I get all authentication. using following code.

> [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"ads_management,xmpp_login,read_stream,read_requests,read_mailbox,read_insights,read_friendlists,email,user_work_history,user_website,user_videos,user_status,user_religion_politics,user_relationships,user_photo_video_tags,user_online_presence,user_notes,user_location,user_likes,user_interests,user_hometown,user_groups,user_events,user_education_history,user_activities,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];

But I can't read phone number and email address.

I use the following Code to read profile:

```
fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me" withGetVars:nil];
```

It depends on the following URL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api.

My profile output is:

> {"id":"1335802454","name":"Vel Murugan","first_name":"Vel","last_name":"Murugan","link":"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1335802454","about":"BE THE BEST OR BE WITH THE BEST","birthday":"05/12/1984","hometown":{"id":106076206097781,"name":"Madurai, India"},"location":{"id":106076206097781,"name":"Madurai, India"},"bio":"Hi","quotes":"What is ur Name?","work":[{"employer":{"id":114941651860886,"name":"yes"},"location":{"id":106076206097781,"name":"Madurai, India"},"position":{"id":106134736085305,"name":"Software developer"},"start_date":"2010-08","end_date":"0000-00","description":"IPHONE APPS DEVELOPER"}],"education":[{"school":{"id":110943172274244,"name":"MCA"},"year":{"id":133774113322262,"name":"2010"}},{"school":{"id":108627612500830,"name":"Bharathidasan University"},"concentration":[{"id":121317831214170,"name":"MCA"},{"id":137092149656664,"name":"Bsc maths"},{"id":151356271549645,"name":"+2"}]}],"gender":"male","relationship_status":"Single","religion":"NO","political":"NO","email":"apps+123145257717248.1335802454.e466b769c10a7745bcb11201de2aae7d@proxymail.facebook.com","website":"http://www.kailasanadhiswarar.org/","timezone":5.5,"locale":"en_US","verified":true,"updated_time":"2010-08-30T18:28:54+0000"}

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the Facebook API does not allow you to get contact informations, such as e-mail and phone number.

Answer (score 1):

I made an application in Flash a couple of month ago, using the Facebook Graph API, and from what I can remember, the recently updated security-restrictions on Facebook prohibits you from accessing your friends email-addresses (might be possible if every friend actively grants your application permission), and as for the phone-number: Is there even a phone-number-parameter in Facebook?

I'm not at all sure about this, but I think that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API does not allow you to get contact informations, such as e-mail and phone number.